# What is the probability that more than x% of the population belongs to category A?

Tags: probability, statistical-significance

There are 100 samples of a population.

40 belong to category A, and 60 belong to category B.

What is the probability that more than 50% of the population belongs to category A?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This question sounds innocent and straightforward enough. It turns out that answering it requires Bayesian methods, meaning that additional assumptions are required. What is the context where this question arose?

Comment: Or do you mean that you want to conduct a hypothesis test and get a p-value? (That is different from what you asked, though why is not obvious for someone who is first learning statistics.)

Comment: Thank you! There are no previous assumptions in this problem. I would like to test the hypothesis that the majority of the population belongs to group A. Is that different from my original question, because testing the null hypothesis through a p-value calculates the p(<50% are A|40/100 are A)? Whereas what I asked for was p(>50% are A). I hope that makes sense, and I appreciate your reply.

Comment: As it stands I don't know how to answer your question. // Maybe this is a useful formulation: If you have $n=100$ people randomly sampled from a population with $p = 1/2$ in Category A, then the number $X$ of Category A people in your sample has dist'n $X \sim\mathsf{Binom}(n=100,p=1/2),$ and $P(X\le 40) =  0.0284.$ Because this probability is smaller than $0.05=5\%$ one says that the null hypothesis that $p\ge1/2$ is rejected at the 5% level (against the alternative hypothesis that $p<1/2.)$ // In R software, where `pbinom` is a binomial CDF, code `pbinom(40, 100, .5)` returns
$0.02844397.$

Comment: Yes, that does help, thank you! I see now the problem is made easier by assuming a 1/2 prior probability and testing on that.